# Google Chrome page load stages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, plugins

I'm trying to develop a plug-in for Chrome and I am facing the following issue:
I couldn't find any mentions about the whole life cycle for how Google Chrome loads a page. I mean, what exactly does the browser while loading a page?

I really need to suppress internal JavaScript execution before my own processing for that html block.

Answer (score 1):

Use the event [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded)

As mentioned in their [linked site](http://molily.de/weblog/domcontentloaded)

> Thus, the DOMContentLoaded is ideal for authors attaching their JavaScript behavior to the page as early as possible.

And here a bit more about the life cycle of loading a page: [How Javascript Loading Works - DOMContentLoaded and OnLoad](http://ablogaboutcode.com/2011/06/14/how-javascript-loading-works-domcontentloaded-and-onload/)

Comment: Thanks Dan,

But that event is processed after INTERNAL javascript code execution. I've tried that approach.